# Do apple charge for user authentication based Apps

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

We are under appstore submission process and recently received following review notes from apple . The app is *free* Authentication based i.e user need to enter username and password .

The review is....

> **We have begun the review of your app but aren't able to continue because we need
>   additional information about your app.  At your
>   earliest opportunity, please review the following questions and
>   provide as detailed information as you can in response. The more
>   information you can provide upfront, the sooner we can complete your
>   review.
>
> 1) How do users obtain an account? What are the costs
>   associated with an account?
>
> 2) Is it subscription based? Or is it a one-time lump sum payment?
>
> 3) Is this available on other platforms?
>
> 4) Does the user pay by device, or by user?
>
> 5) Is there an additional
>   charge for mobile access?**

So i have couple of queries , Because this was our new version with few UI changes of previously uploaded app to appstore, however apple didn't ask about such information during first App Store submission   ....

1. Do we need to provide them all cost/user subscription related information ?
2. Is apple undergoing such process for all user authentication based apps ? What can be the purpose of apple for asking such business related information.
3. Do we need to pay apple, so that our customers can use our services....?

Regards

Pagyyy123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't charge your user, just state this and Apple may be happy. My guess is that Apple asks this, because they would like to see you using their in-App purchasing system (if you made use of paid subscriptions). One of my (completely free) apps included user authentication and all they asked for was a demo account to test the functionality. Answering the title-question: no, Apple does not charge for user authentication based apps.

Regarding the first question ("how does the user obtain an account?"): if your App does not provide such functionality, you should provide a link to a website that handles this task.

In general: SO may not be the best place to ask this question, but the Apple support definitely is.

Comment: But apple didn't ask during first appstore submission of the same app

Comment: This could be due to different reviewers (one handling it more strictly than another)

Comment: A previous approval does not set a sort of precedent that an app actually complies with all of Apple's rules and guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Do we need to provide them all cost/user subscription related information ?

Yes. You have to abide by the app store rules.

> 1. Is apple undergoing such process for all user authentication based apps ? What can be the purpose of apple for asking such business related information.

Yes, they do that for all authentication based apps. You have to provide a way to create an account from the app.

> 1. Do we need to pay apple, so that our customers can use our services....?

No